# DiscountASP.NET/shared hosting

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, hosting, asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of trying to source an ASP.NET MVC3/SQL2008 host and think I'm happy with DiscountASP.NET however I have a few questions which I can't seem to find answers to:

1) What sort of CPU will my site be allocated and what sort of CPU backs the SQL server DB? Or is this a dumb question with shared hosting? I am struggling to understand what sort of performance I can expect.

2) As per above, what are the memory limitations? I think its 200mb before the shared pool gets recycled (which is OK) but what about the SQL server DB?

3) Has anyone got any experience of the SQL server setup they offer? Some report that its overpriced - it doesn't appear to be to me but then I don't know of a recommended alternative.

Thanks

Comment: Please read our FAQ to understand what this before contributing again.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to say, but what makes you tnhink ifi s a good idea to ask that on a public forum of people totally unrelated to the technical suppot staff os DiscountASP.NET contrary to actually running ot to the people kniowing - whbich is the technical team at DiscountASP.NET, available through a ton of contact means available through their website?

Comment: It was more of a general question perhaps I shouldn't have referred to DiscountASP.NET. I appreciate your response even if the tone is a little condescending. There are a ton of DiscountASP.NET/shared hosting questions on here which have answers hence I didn't see this as any different.

Comment: Yours is a shopping question which is generally fwowned upon and not welcome here. YOu are VERY specific and make clear you have not even tried solving it with the people in quesstion. This is why my answer got upvoted and the question closed.